# Conditions for JPA OneToMany collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

If I have this entity:

```
@Entity
class Pet {

    @Id
    long id;

    public enum State { ALIVE, DEAD }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @...
    State state;

    @...
    String name;

}
```

Can I create a mapping like this:

```
@Entity
class Owner {

    @OneToMany(condition="state = ALIVE") // or something like that
    Set<Pet> alivePets;

    @OneToMany(condition="state = DEAD")
    Set<Pet> deadPets;

}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As far as I know this is not part of the JPA spec. At least Hibernates JPA implementation provides an own annotation `@Where` which can be used:

```
@OneToMany
@Where(clause = "state = 'ALIVE'")
Set<Pet> alivePets
```

Comment: I'm already using some Hibernate specific features, so that would be ok.

Comment: I see, you have changed your question. To explain my answer a little bit more: the @Where clause refers to the db value of the state column in your pet table. So please check if it works also with your enum State.

Comment: Yes, I always map enums as strings.